# CORS request to DropWizard based API failing in IE, Edge and Safari but working in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: safari, cors, dropwizard, microsoft-edge

I am using Dropwizard v1.0.0 and implemented CORS but requested to it is failing in Safari, IE and Edge. However, it is working in Firefox and Chrome.

```
FilterRegistration.Dynamic cors = environment.servlets()
            .addFilter("CORSFilter", CrossOriginFilter.class);

cors.setInitParameter(ALLOWED_ORIGINS_PARAM, "*");
cors.setInitParameter(ALLOWED_HEADERS_PARAM, "Content-Type,Access-Control-Allow-Origin,Authorization");
cors.setInitParameter(ALLOWED_METHODS_PARAM, "OPTIONS,HEAD,DELETE,GET,PUT,POST,PATCH,HEAD");
cors.addMappingForUrlPatterns(EnumSet.allOf(DispatcherType.class), true, "/*");
```

This code is applied in XYZApplication.java.

Error message which I am getting in console is:

> Failed to load resource: Origin https://xyz.in is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Here are the OPTIONS request headers from Edge:

```
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Access-Control-Request-Headers: access-control-allow-origin,authorization, accept
Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 0
Host: xyz-api.in
Origin: https://xyz.in
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.79 Safari/537.36 Edge/14.14393
```

Here are the OPTIONS request headers from Chrome:

```
Host: xyz-api.in
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
Origin: https://xyz.in
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.35 Safari/537.36
Access-Control-Request-Headers: access-control-allow-origin, authorization
Accept: */*
Referer: https://xyz.in/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
```

Please let me know what I have missed or any other detail required.

Comment: "it is failing" is not a good description of the problem. How is it failing? What error messages are reported in the developer tools console? What does the Network tab say? What is different about the combination of requests and responses for the browsers which work and those which fail?

Comment: @Quentin added more details including the error message in console and request headers on Chrome and Edge. Please let me know if any more details are required.

Comment: "Origin https://xyz.in is not allowed" … "Origin: https://xyz.zapr.in" … "Origin: https://adimprints.zapr.in" — **none of these origins match**, it looks like you have three different pages and that the requests are triggers by two of them and the error message is from a request from a third.

Comment: @Quentin I have 1 dashboard i.e. xyz.in and 1 api (xyz-api.in).
I have rectified the details.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import static javax.ws.rs.core.HttpHeaders.*;

FilterRegistration.Dynamic cors = environment.servlets()
    .addFilter("CORSFilter", CrossOriginFilter.class);

cors.addMappingForUrlPatterns(EnumSet.allOf(DispatcherType.class), false, environment.getApplicationContext().getContextPath() + "*");
cors.setInitParameter(ALLOWED_METHODS_PARAM, "GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,HEAD,OPTIONS");
cors.setInitParameter(ALLOWED_ORIGINS_PARAM, "*");
cors.setInitParameter(ALLOWED_HEADERS_PARAM, "*");
cors.setInitParameter(EXPOSED_HEADERS_PARAM, "Link");
cors.setInitParameter(ALLOW_CREDENTIALS_PARAM, "true");
```